# Rough Idling in Citroen C4

Tags: rough-idle, citroen

I have got a Citroen C4 1.6 litres petrol engine. I have been experiencing rough idling, engine vibration and also engine stalls when accelerating and it will pick up speed gradually. Does anyone have any idea of where to diagnose and fix the issue in Coventry area without the mechanic requiring my arm and leg? I have checked on the forum and realised it is much more than i can do by myself or ask someone who doesn't have much mechanical knowledge handle for me

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we're not able to provide shopping assistance here as it becomes out of date too quickly, and is too localised. Your best bet is to try something like 'checkatrade', or ask around friends/colleagues to see who they recommend.